# JavaFX - css adding background image with transparency

Tags: java, css, javafx, background-image

I want to add an image (png) this way:

```
#leftCorner {
  -fx-background-image: url("images/backgroundTrain2.png");
  -fx-background-repeat: stretch;
  -fx-background-size: 150.0 71.0;
  -fx-background-position: center center;
}
```

the problem is that I loose the transparency of the white part of the image.
Can somebody tell me what I can do that it stays transparent?

[image]

thats the picture i try to add as background

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use `-fx-background-color:transparent` to set pngs on my Buttons and transparency works. Try this.

Comment: I checked your image it doesnt have transparency, check once in photoshop if possible.

Comment: thx - seems like i failed - ps.: I dont have photoshop - made this with mspaint and thought when I save it as png the white part is automatically transparent

Comment: No MSPaint is "over"smart, it will fill up png transparent parts with white...if not photoshop then use gimp for preparing such pngs :)

Answer (score 4):

-fx-opacity: 0.5;

Add this to your ID in fx css file